# Eclipse build fail issue

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment

I deployed my java web application in eclipse kepler. But when i clean and build my project i got a prompt from eclipse and it look like follows

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'MY_PROJECT'.
Launch configuration type id "org.maven.ide.eclipse.Maven2BuilderConfigurationType" does not exist.
Possible causes:
    Missing specification of a launch type (missing plug-in)
    Incorrect launch configuration XML
Launch configuration type id "org.maven.ide.eclipse.Maven2BuilderConfigurationType" does not exist.
Possible causes:
    Missing specification of a launch type (missing plug-in)
    Incorrect launch configuration XML
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of missing of some plug-ins. So what you can do is delete all recent plug-in and make one new workspace and in that you can again launch your Web Project with inserting all plug-ins again.

And also at time of deployment, make sure that you are creating new Apache server again.Dont use created server again.